# Spreadsheet Matching Cells

Tags: google-sheets

Hello Guys could you help me with formula.

I have
Cell "A1" contain "NJ"
Cell "B1" Contain "NY"

I want to have C1 to return "Long Distance"

Or

If Cell "A1" contain NJ
Cell "B1" Contain NJ
I want to have C1 to return "Local"

Thank you so much for you help.

I have tried Index formula but didnt work.

Comment: The criteria is 2nd char?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF(A1=B1; "Local"; "Long Distance")
```